# Git revert command error

Tags: git, git-revert

While I am reverting a particular commit in git repository it gives the following error :

```
Command for reverting is  **git revert <commit-hash>**

error: Commit <commit-hash> is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: revert failed
```

Can any one please explain why this error coming?

-Thanks 
Krishna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `git revert` to "back out" a change, it needs to figure out what the change was.

In the case of most ordinary commits, the change is easy to compute.  Consider for instance this git commit graph fragment:

```
... - G - H ...    <-- HEAD=master
```

Here you're on branch `master` which has commits `G`, `H`, and then some more.

If you ask git to revert commit `H`, it simply needs to see what changed between "everything in revision `G`" and "everything in revision `H`".  Git can do this the same way you can, by comparing `G` and `H`:

```
$ git diff <sha1-of-G> <sha1-of-H>
```

If this says that in commit `H`, you added one line to file `readme.txt` and removed file `x.h` entirely, then git can undo this by removing that one line from `readme.txt` and restoring file `x.h` from commit `G`.

Merge commits are more complex, though.  Let's fill in some more of that commit graph:

```
              I - J
            /       \
... - G - H           M - N - O  <-- HEAD=master
            \       /
              K - L
```

If you ask git to revert the merge commit `M`, what changes should it back out?

There's one set of changes in going from `J` to `M`:

```
$ git diff <sha1-of-J> <sha1-of-M>
```

(these changes are, in fact, the changes brought in via commit `L` as compared to commit `H`, which will be the changes from commits `K` and `L` combined).

There's another, likely quite different, set of changes going from `L` to `M`:

```
$ git diff <sha1-of-L> <sha1-of-M>
```

(these changes are actually those in `I` and `J`, by similar logic).

You must tell git *which* set of changes to undo, and which to keep.  Git has you do this by specifying the "main line".  This also relies on the fact that the parent IDs stored in a merge commit are *in a specific order*.

Let's say you were on commit `J`, which was `master`, when you made the merge:

```
$ git checkout master   # i.e., commit J
$ git merge branch      # i.e., commit L
```

Now you are on commit `O`, which is still `master`.  The branch name `branch` may no longer exist (or might point to some commit other than `L`), but you want to discard the changes in both `K` and `L`—i.e., the ones that were on branch `branch` when you did the merge.

The *first* parent of `M` is `J`, because you merged `branch` into `master`, which git records by making `J` the first parent and `L` the second parent.  Thus, to discard the changes from commits `K` and `L`, you could now use:

```
$ git revert -m 1 HEAD~2
```

(here `HEAD~2` backs up two commits, from `O` to `N` and then to `M`).  Git can then diff `M^1` (`J`) against `M`, which finds the changes introduced by merging in branch `branch` as noted above; and then reversing those changes results in backing out the changes introduced by the merge.

Note that this makes a new commit, resulting in a graph that looks like this:

```
              I - J
            /       \
... - G - H           M - N - O - P   <-- HEAD=master
            \       /
              K - L
```

where comparing commits `O` and `P` produces essentially the same thing as comparing `M` and `J` (in that order, i.e., the reverse of the "normal" compare from `J` to `M`).  As far as later operations in git are concerned, though, you might as well have done this by hand-editing the tree for `O` and making the new commit `P`: it does not record (except in the commit message text) that `P` is essentially a revert of both `K` and `L`.

---

Incidentally, it's worth noting that in this particular case, you could simply revert `L` first, then revert `K`, to (probably) get the same effect (with two separate extra commits):

```
$ L=$(git rev-parse HEAD~2^2)   # get sha-1 ID of commit L
$ git revert $L                 # make new commit P that reverts L
$ git revert $L^                # make new commit Q that reverts L^ = K
```

With a big merge, though, reverting each individual change is a lot of work; reverting the merge commit itself is much easier (both to do, and to understand later, if properly documented).  (Also, the "probably" above is because the merge handles identical changes made on "both sides" of the branch, and reverting the merge avoids undoing changes in `K` and `L` that were *not* brought forward into `M` because they *also* occurred in `I` and/or `J`.  However, this is somewhat rare, especially in tiny branching structures like this.)

Answer (score 4):

Just read the fine [manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) :-):

> Usually you cannot revert a merge because you do not know which side
>   of the merge should be considered the mainline.  This option specifies the parent number 
>   (starting from 1) of the mainline and allows revert to reverse the change relative to 
>   the specified parent.
>
> [...]
>
> Reverting a merge commit declares that you will never want the tree
>   changes brought in by the merge. As a result, later merges will only
>   bring in tree changes introduced by commits that are not ancestors of
>   the previously reverted merge. This may or may not be what you want.

The problem is that a merge commit is a more complicated thing than a regular commit - it does not only change files, it also links two branches together. When reverting it, you must decide (and tell git) whether you only want to roll back the file changes it introduces, or also the linking of the branches.

- If you want to roll back the changes, but keep the linking of the branches, use option `-m` to `git merge` as explained in the manpage.
- If you want to completely undo the merge, you must rewrite history (using a combination of `git rebase`, `git reset` and `git cherry-pick`), with all [the complications that can bring](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

What you need depends on why you are reverting the commit.